# Do Fourier coefficients (and series) of $f(x):\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ and $f(x+2012)$ are the same?

Tags: calculus

I'd like to know whether Fourier  coefficients (and series) of $f(x):\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ and $f(x+c)$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$ are the same and if so, why?

I have this question where $f$ is a $ 2 \pi$ periodic and Continuously differential which it's Fourier coefficient is $3^{-n^2}$, I need to compute $g$'s Fourier coefficient, where $g(x)=\pi f'(x+2011)$. eventually I got that $\hat{g(n)}=\pi i n \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-inx}f(x+2011 )$ and I would like to say that   $\hat{g(n)}=\pi i n\hat{f(n)}=\pi i n3^{-n^2}$, I'm just not sure if it is correct.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to think: you probably know that if $f$ is a $C^1$, $2\pi$-periodic function, its Fourier series converges uniformly to $f$, hence if the coefficients were the same you'd have the same series and the same function at the end. So unless $f$ is 2012-periodic (and since $f$ is also $2\pi$ periodic it can only happen in one case: which one?), then no the coefficients are not the same.

As for computing the actual coefficients, try as AD. suggests.

Answer (score 0):

No not really.

*Hints:*

1. Change the variable of integration in your expression for $\hat{g}(n)$.
2. Use an exp-rule.
3. What happens to the "area of integration" - perhaps you can you split it up and use periodicity?

Comment: My humble suggestion: You could leave hints that take fewer than 10 words to write such as this in the comments. If you want to give a series of steps, then it's too long for a comment and hence, you could answer. No offense.

Comment: In which case a comment would have done. Never mind!

Comment: @KannappanSampath Thank you Kannappan, I rewrote my answer. :)